# How to cancel this noise to find numbers of DTMF tones?

Tags: frequency-response, noise-cancellation

Touch-tone telephones use a dual tone multi frequency (DTMF) scheme to encode key-presses as audio tones:
[image]

I have a signal containing 10 number tones. I used frequency response to show what frequencies the signal has, but they are affected by noise (I think this is white noise). Can you suggest me a way to cancel this noise to find frequencies of numbers encoded. Here is frequency response of each number in the signal:
[image]

Example: Frequency response of another signal that doesn't have noise, I can compare and find numbers encoded:
[image]

My professor gave me two audio data files, one is tones without noise and another is tones with noise. I used DTFT to plot each tone in each file:
[image]
[image]

Comment: How are you generating these responses? Could you add details?

Comment: My professor gave me two audio data files, one is tones without noise and another is tones with noise. I used DTFT to generate the responses of each number(tone). I just attached my progarm to generate the reponses in the main post.Thank for response!